# prolog: reduce then write the value of a predicate

Tags: prolog

This is some of the code I am writing

```
assert(bar(foo)),
assert(foo(bar-5)),
```

I'm not sure if it works though. I'm trying to get it to reduce foo by 5. I need a way to write the value of foo, but haven't found a way too.
`write('foo is' + foo)` would be the logical way to me, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use a fact's value you have to unify it first. Unification is done passing unbound variable as an argument to a predicate, — `bar(Moo)` in our case:

```
facts
    bar(integer)
    foo(integer)

goal
    assert(bar(42)),
    bar(Moo),
    Baz = Moo - 5,
    assert(foo(Baz)),
    write(Baz).
```

Comment: I thought that `retract/1` is for removing facts from database/table. `bar(Moo)` should try to unify, but leaving dynamic facts untouched, I guess.

Comment: @ony: Sure, I just implied that fact `foo` should be retracted before we can put it (un)changed to the facts base, otherwise we'd end up with 2 facts, update.

Comment: @Kaarel: This is Visual Prolog 5.2, didn't have any other at the moment of writing.